# Haskell foldM from list to a single Either

Tags: haskell

I'm writing an interpreter of sorts in Haskell, it's been super interesting so far. I'm in the Codegen step (take the parser result, pretty print it into code), One thing I tried to do is the following:

I have Modules and my modules have declarations.

```
codegen :: Module -> Either String ByteString
codegen Module { what = "module", declarations = decls } = Right $ foldM (\output decl ->
    output ++ (codegenDecl decl)) (empty :: ByteString) decls -- generate declarations    
codegen Module { what = s } = Left $ "Bad module 'what' key " ++ s

codegenDecl :: Declaration -> Either String ByteString
codegenDecl Declaration { what = dt, name = dn, argnames = Just al, constructors = Just lc } = Right $ "Declaration " ++ dn ++ " of type " ++ dt
```

The pattern-matched variable `decls` is `decls :: [Declaration]` and I'm using the Either monad for error tracking. What I expect from

`foldM (\output decl ->
        output ++ (codegenDecl decl)) (empty :: ByteString) decls`

Is to concat all the ByteStrings if all the declarations are correct, or return a `Left $ "Error writing a declaration"`

But I think I'm missing a couple of things here as the typecheker complains. If either of the declarations fails, I want the whole Module to fail. If all of them succeed, I want to concatenate them into one ByteString.

```
[decls] --------> Right result -------> Right $ foldM (++) accumulator result                                                      |
    |                 ^                                 |
    |                 -----------------------------------
    |
    |-----------> Left err ------------> Left $ err
```

The bottom part seems to be what the >>= operator does for Either, so that makes me think there's a stylish, monadic way to do what I want without cases and the such. I'd be curious to find out what's the best style here.

Comment: About "the typecheker complains": when that happens, you should always post the (full) error message. Otherwise, you force readers to perform type checking in their head trying to figure what's wrong, or trying to build a MCVE from your code -- both requiring non trivial effort. This makes it less likely that someone will answer your question.

Comment: Do you want something like `concat <$> mapM codegenDecl decls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to the question, since it doesn't address your questions about `foldM`... but I wouldn't even use `foldM` at all. I think it's cleaner to do all your `codegenDecl`ing, then concatenate the results separately. This will have two advantages:

1. It will do a single `ByteString` concatenation operation, which can build an appropriately-sized buffer first then walk it once to fill it. This will be more efficient than doing repeated appends, which will have to rewalk early `ByteString`s many times and allocate many buffers.
2. Because it uses combinators that can "do less stuff" -- `mapM` instead of `foldM` -- the reader can pay less attention and still come to the right conclusion about what's happening.

Here's how that would look:

```
mconcat <$> mapM codegenDecl decls
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! So just a clarification, mconcat will not actually concat in case the result array has multiple “Left errors” right?

Comment: @rausted Correct: as soon as `codegenDecl` returns a `Left` for one of the `decls`, the entire computation will immediately abort and return that `Left`.

Answer (score 2):

- `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` appends lists
- `output :: ByteString`
- `codegenDecl decl :: Either String ByteString`

`output` doesn't match the expected type of the first argument of `(++)` (unless it was redefined somewhere, e.g., in basic-prelude), and `codegenDecl` doesn't match the expected type of the second argument of `(++)`.

This lambda should typecheck (with `(<>)` from `Data.Monoid`):

```
\output decl -> fmap (output <>) (codegenDecl decl)
```